# Android large String array alternatives

Tags: java, android, arrays, performance

I have a list view on my activity that I want to implement a input search feature for the list view and have access to the filters. However, there are a lot of Strings in the array to the point that the activity takes a while to load or crashes.

Currently I am only able to store in a quarter of the Strings in the String array before it crashes. I've tried adding the Strings programmatically and also through XML as described in the android document.

What would be the best alternatives to store the information rather than keeping them in a String array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about showing some code so that others can help?

Comment: One way would be to maintain a small LRUMap in memory and store all string in a file. If for a search there is hit, directly return from the Map. If not, then stream data from file and then display and save in Map.

Comment: Another way is to show only 10/20 items each time, with a button to "load more"

Comment: @Nirel Thats a great idea. I think i'll implement that if I cant think of anythign else.

Comment: use `sqlite` db for that + `SimpleCursorAdapter` + `FilterQueryProvider` - it shouldn't take more than dozen lines (or at most two) of effective code

Comment: @pskink I'll look into that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load items partially, for example first 30, if user wants more he will click `view more` button. (Good practice)
2. Try to write your `Strings` to file, and then read them when needed.

Comment: Thanks. I think i'll have to look at writing Strings to a file as ill need all the strings to be together inorder for the search filter to filter through all items.

Comment: if you want to store many strings, you also may use `SQLite`, it is file db, very light. So, you will just make `sql` requests.