# Is it good to store data in array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I start making Quiz game , I have 700 question Quiz problems to store in my app ,So i store all of my Quiz question in Array
it work fine but it is good to store my Quiz Question in array? or Should I use database?

Comment: I'd say yes - while Array is great for runtime ( provided you have enough memory to store it ), having everything hardcoded into array can be a pain and requires you to recompile the whole application to change any question. While database would allow you to even hotswap questions with application still running, or allow for implementation of button triggered updates to questionbase.

Comment: A little more context would be useful to understand the requirements and answer your question. Do you need to search for the problems in any way? How are u using those question?

Comment: imo data isn't a part of behavior, and shouldn't sit in the code.

Comment: You are better off using a database. `Firebase RTDB` or `Firestore` are the ones I use.

Comment: If it works for your use case why not? But keep in mind if you plan to expand your application, make sure that you are programming by interface. Meaning that in the future we can change this array implementation into a database.

Putting it in an array or database or whatever is an implementation detail and a good design is to be able to defer decisions with cases like this.

Bottom line is, if it works for you right now, why not? Just keep in mind to make it easier to swap the implementation.

Comment: How will you populate the array again when user relaunches the app ?

Answer (score 0):

As many have stated in the comments, if it is working fine, why to worry. However, if in some devices loading that much data is a problem I would suggest two options.

1. Proceed as explained here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478067/9415337).
2. Load the data/create the array asynchronously and, when finished, remove the loading bar/... and start.

Hope it helps!